# Trying to print one element of an array somehow prints all elements

Tags: arrays, perl

I am writing a script to take a list of integers from file `aryData`, sort them, print the sorted array, the highest value, and the lowest value.

#### aryData

```
89 62 11 75 8 33 95 4
```

But when printing the highest or lowest value, all elements of the array are printed.

This is my Perl code

```
#!/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

print "Enter filename to be sorted: ";
my $filename = <STDIN>;
chomp( $filename );

open( INFILE, "<$filename" );
my @nums = <INFILE>;
close INFILE;

my @sorted = sort { $a cmp $b } @nums;

open my $outfile, '>', "HighLow.txt";

print $outfile "Sorted numbers: @sorted";
print $outfile "Smallest number: $sorted[0] \n";
print $outfile "Largest number: $sorted[-1] \n";
```

#### output `HighLow.txt`

```
Sorted numbers: 89 62 11 75 8 33 95 4
Smallest number: 89 62 11 75 8 33 95 4
Largest number: 89 62 11 75 8 33 95 4
```

Comment: Can you find out how many entries your array has? It looks like it only has one.

Comment: If all the numbers are on one line in the file you need to `split` them. Your array only has one item. You can also see that because they are not sorted in your first line of output.

Comment: all the numbers are saved in single array index, you have to store each element in one array index, for that use `split` just like @simbabque suggested

Comment: This moreover seems like a homework question for me

Comment: And comparing numbers is done by using `<=>` not `cmp`.

Comment: It might be homework, but it contains code that looks mostly fine. It contains a proper description of the problem, and it asks a very specific question. Even if it's just a matter of having forgotten one step, I think it's a perfectly valid and good question. They would have figured out out with a bit of debugging but they likely don't know how, or that such a thing exists at all.

Comment: @simbabque, yes it contains good description, I have experienced users just deleting their questions(homework) after someone answers it. Just hoping that this will not end in the same way.

Comment: Yes this is homework. Is homework not allowed on Stack Overflow? I'm a student who just got introduced to Perl scripting today. I did what I could. I do thank you for the "split" tip, I did not know about that. Since my numbers are all on one line, right now is the array essentially filling just the first element with a string of numbers?

Comment: @nhershy don't take it harsh, your question is absolutely fine, you could improve your wordings in the question not to sound like homework. Thats what I meant.

Comment: homework is fine. It just shouldn't be "Here is my task I need a solution". You did everything right. I'll write you an answer with explanation on how to debug this problem when I'm at a computer. Welcome to Stack Overflow and to Perl! :-)

Comment: I'd really appreciate that! Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer will have a large portion of code review and explain concepts that are not directly related to the question.

Let's look at the part of your code that reads in the array.

```
open(INFILE, "<$filename");
my @nums = <INFILE>;
close INFILE;
```

This code is fine for what you are doing, but it has a few security and style issues that I will get into further below.

So you have a file name, and you read in a file line by line. Each line goes into one element in the array `@nums`. Since your stuff is not working the way you want, the first step you need to take to debug this is to try to look at the array.

Your attempt to do this was not a bad idea.

```
print "Sorted numbers: @sorted";
```

[Interpolating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation) an array in a double quoted `""` string in Perl joins the the elements of the array with the variable `$,`, which is also known as the [output field separator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#24%2C). By default, it's a blank space .

```
my @foo = (1, 2, 3);
print "@foo";
```

This will give the following output

```
1 2 3
```

Unfortunately your input file already had spaces as separators, and all numbers were on one line. So you couldn't really see that the array wasn't properly set up. That's one of those facepalm moments when you notice it yourself. You *could have noticed* it by looking at the sorted numbers. You did sort them, but they were not sorted.

> ```
> Sorted numbers: 89 62 11 75 8 33 95 4
> ```

A better way to figure out what's in the array would be to use [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper), which lets you [serialize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) data structures. It's included with Perl.

```
use Data::Dumper;

my @foo = (1, 2, 3);
print Dumper \@foo;
```

The module gives you a `Dumper` function. It likes works better on references, so you need to add the backslash to create a reference to `@foo`. What that means exactly is not relevant at this point. Just remember that if your variable does not have a `$`, you put a backslash in front.

```
$VAR1 = [
          1,
          2,
          3
        ];
```

This is useful. It tells us the three elements. Now lets look at your code. Instead of an actual file, I am using the pseudo-filehandle `DATA`, which reads from the `__DATA__` section at the end of the program. This is great for testing and for examples.

```
use Data::Dumper;

my @nums = <DATA>;
my @sorted = sort { $a cmp $b } @nums;

print Dumper \@sorted;

__DATA__
89 62 11 75 8 33 95 4
```

This prints

```
$VAR1 = [
          '89 62 11 75 8 33 95 4
'
        ];
```

We can see two things here. First, all numbers are on one line, and thus they went into the first element. Second, the line has a newline at the end. You already know that you can remove that with `chomp`.

So lets try to fix this. We now know that we need to [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) the line of numbers. [There are many different ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it) to accomplish this task. I will go with a very verbose one to explain the steps involved.

```
use Data::Dumper;

my $line = <DATA>;    # only read one line
chomp $line;          # remove the line ending

my @nums = split / /, $line;
my @sorted = sort { $a cmp $b } @nums;

print Dumper \@sorted;

__DATA__
89 62 11 75 8 33 95 4
```

We use `split` with an empty *pattern* `/ /` to turn the string of numbers into a list of numbers, and put that in an array. Then we sort.

```
$VAR1 = [
          '11',
          '33',
          '4',
          '62',
          '75',
          '8',
          '89',
          '95'
        ];
```

As you can see, we now have a sorted list of numbers. But they are not sorted numerically. Instead, they are [sorted *asciibetically*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Character_order). That's because [`cmp` is the operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators) that sorts by [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) character number. It's also the default behavior of Perl's `sort`, so you could have omitted that whole `{ $a cmp $b }` block. It's the same as just saying `sort @nums`.

But we want to sort numbers by their numerical value, so we need to use the `<=>` sorting operator.

```
use Data::Dumper;

my $line = <DATA>;    # only read one line
chomp $line;          # remove the line ending

my @nums = split / /, $line;
my @sorted = sort { $a <=> $b } @nums;

print Dumper \@sorted;

__DATA__
89 62 11 75 8 33 95 4
```

Now the program prints the right output.

```
$VAR1 = [
          '4',
          '8',
          '11',
          '33',
          '62',
          '75',
          '89',
          '95'
        ];
```

I'll leave it to you to put this back into your actual program.

---

Finally, a word about your `open`. You are using what's called *glob filehandles*. Those things like `INFILE` are global identifiers. They are valid throughout your program, even in other modules that you might load. While in this tiny program that doesn't really make a difference, it might cause problems in the future. If for example the Data::Dumper module was to open a file and use the same identifier `INFILE`, and you had not called `close INFILE`, your program might either crash or do very weird things, because it would reuse the same handle.

Instead, you can use a *lexical* file handle. A lexical variable is only valid inside of a certain scope, like a function or the body of a loop. It's just a regular variable, declared with `my`. It will automatically call `close` for you when it *goes out of scope*.

```
open my $fh, "<foo";
my @nums = <$fh>;
close $fh;
```

You are calling `open` with two arguments. That's also not a good idea. Right now you have the mode `<`, but if you leave that out and do `open my $fh, "$file"` and read the `$file` from the user, they might pass in bad things, like `| rm -rf slash`. Perl will then treat the pipe `|` as the mode, open a pipe and delete all your stuff. Instead, use three-argument open.

```
open my $fh, '<', 'foo';
```

Now that you explicitly set the mode, you're safe.

The last point is that you should always check if `open` worked. That's easy.

```
open my $fh, '<', 'foo' or die $!;
```

The [variable `$!`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Error-Variables) contains the error that `open` encountered. The `or` will only trigger if the return value of the `open` call was false. And `die` makes the program terminate. The error you might receive could look like this.

> No such file or directory at /home/foo/code/scratch.pl line 6154.

So the full file reading should look something like this.

```
open my $fh, '<', $filename or die "Could not read $filename: $!";
my @nums = <$fh>;
close $fh;
```

Comment: @DaveCross Looks like for once I did :)

Answer (score 2):

As you've seen from the comments, the problem here is that you don't populate your array correctly. You end up with only one element in `@nums` - it's a single element that contains all of your data.

You could confirm that by using something like `Data::Dumper`, which... er... dumps your data :-)

At the top of your program, just after the `use warnings;` you can add this:

```
use Data::Dumper;
```

Then after you have loaded up `@nums`, try dumping it:

```
print Dumper(\@nums), "\n";
```

You'll see this:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '89 62 11 75 8 33 95 4
'
        ];
```

Compare that to what you see when we fix your problem and you'll see an obvious difference.

So we have a line of data that contains the numbers you're interested in separated by spaces. To convert that into a list of numbers which we can store in your array, we can use the `split()` function. `split()` takes two arguments - a regular expression to split the string on, and the string to split.

You have this code to read from the file and assign to your array:

```
my @nums = <INFILE>;
```

You can replace that with:

```
my @nums = split / /, <INFILE>;
```

Now our data dump looks like this:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '89',
          '62',
          '11',
          '75',
          '8',
          '33',
          '95',
          '4
'
        ];
```

I hope the difference is obvious. Your program basically works at this point, but we can clean things up a bit by dealing with the new-line at the end of the record in the file (you can see it after the `4` above).

We'll need to split the line into two.

```
chomp(my $input = <INFILE>);
my @nums = split / /, $input;
```

Now our data dump looks like this:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '89',
          '62',
          '11',
          '75',
          '8',
          '33',
          '95',
          '4'
        ];
```

At this point, your program still has a bug left in it. I'm going to leave that for you to investigate (hint: what does `sort()` actually do? [Read the documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html)) - if you have more problems, please ask another question.

But I'd like to finish by suggesting some improvements to your general coding style. I'm not sure where you're learning Perl from, but some of the stuff you're doing looks pretty dated.

When you open a file in Perl, you should always check the results from your call to open and take appropriate action if it fails. In many cases, killing the program is the appropriate action, so I'd use `die()` in your open statement.

```
open( INFILE, "<$filename" )
  or die "Can't open $filename: $!\n");
```

The `$!` in the error message will tell you why Perl couldn't open the file.

It's also regarded as best practice these days to avoid "bareword filehandles" (like your `INFILE`) and also split the file name from the mode indicators (`>` or `<`). Putting that all together, your file handling code becomes:

```
open( my $in_fh, '<', $filename )
  or die "Can't open $filename: $!\n";
chomp(my $input = <$in_fh>);
my @nums = split / /, $input;
close $in_fh;
```

I see you are already using this style for the output file. Seems strange to mix the styles within the same program.

Comment: And then we actually have almost the same content. Even the code is the same. So much for TIMTOWTDI. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe You can try this to find out the max and min:

```
@a=qw(1 3 2 8 7 5 4 10 9);
@a=sort {$a<=>$b}@a;
print "the max number=$a[0]\nthe min number=$a[$#a]\n";
```

Comment: Please use strict and warnings in code examples and provide code that works under them. The OP already knows how to get the min and max. You're right about the sorting operator, but you don't explain why. Please try to improve your answer. You're giving an answer, not a guess. ;-)

Comment: @Nagaraju where the numbers come from doesn't really matter. One of your first lessons in programming is to learn how to do abstraction. Treat each thing as an individual problem. You already know how to read a file. So it actually doesn't matter that that is not included here. Instead they just created an array. It's about the concept, not the exact code. Don't worry, you'll get there in time.

Comment: yeah fine @simbabque, not a big problem